# Remove the ampersand tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Yes, we have an [ampersand](/questions/tagged/ampersand) tag. Over two-hundred questions are in it right now.

I'll start looking at the questions that could survive without the tag, and edit/close the ones that can't.  While we're at it, could we get a burnination here?

Comment: I cleaned up a few questions. There are 209 remaining. 34 unanswered.

Comment: Oh geez, I didn't realize I had derped that hard.  Let me update that number real fast...

Comment: I softly disagree.  For a long time, it's been difficult, if not impossible, to search for punctuation.  This tag might serve or assist in that purpose.

Comment: What questions about punctuation aren't considered meta tags, though?  The tag description doesn't give any good indication to its real purpose, and it's being used in all sorts of encoding/XML/REST questions, where there are more suitable tags for it.

Comment: Good point.  Keep in mind that people with poor tagging skill often also have poor problem explaining skills.  When doing a cleanup, be sure to solve other problems with the question and use closevotes and downvotes as appropriate.

Comment: @Charles it's enough for text to appear in title. Do we need tags for everything someone might like to look for?

Answer (score 6):

Well i think ..
[image: Burninate!]

Comment: **+1** for custom graphic

Comment: But the graphic misses some hand drawn red circles. Bah!